# Are there any non-mammalian species known that lactate?

Tags: physiology, mammals, milk

Are there any non-mammalian animals that produce milk to feed their young, or are mammals the only milk-producing animals?

Comment: The classical definition of a mammal includes production of milk (hence the name). Your question is a bit circular unless you specify your definition of a mammal.

Comment: @Superbest: in which case, equivalently, "are mammals a clade?", to which we can reply, "no, because not all common ancestors of pigeons and humans produce milk", or reply "yes, by a No True Scotsman argument" ;-)

Comment: Related question: [Do any birds beside the family Columbidae (or any reptile or mammal) feed their young "Crop Milk"](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5127/do-any-birds-beside-the-family-columbidae-or-any-reptile-or-mammal-feed-their)

Comment: one can find pretty detailed examples and a possible explanation in this [article](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20150725-breastfeeding-has-ancient-origins)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**Short answer**
Technically, only mammals lactate. To *[lactate](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lactate)* means *to produce milk from the mammaries to feed a baby or young animal*. [*Milk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk), in turn, is defined as the secretions from mammary glands. However, there are animals other than mammals that produce milk-*like* substances to feed their young.

**Background**
Both male and female **pigeons** (*Columba livia*) possess the ability to produce a nutrient substance, termed pigeon ‘milk’, to feed their young. A similar substance is produced by **flamingos** and male **emperor penguins**. The normal function of a crop is a food storage area located between the oesophagus and proventriculus where food is moistened before further break-down and digestion through the gastrointestinal tract (Fig. 1).

[image: pigeon] [image: dove]
<sup>Fig. 1. Schematic of the location of the 'milk'-producing crop in a pigeon (left) and a pigeon feeding its chick from its crop (right). Sources: [ZME Science](http://www.zmescience.com/medicine/genetic/fancy-a-cup-of-pigeon-milk/) and [Bird Ecology Study Group](http://www.besgroup.org/2011/07/31/peaceful-dove-feeding-juveniles-with-crop-milk/)</sup>

During the process of pigeon ‘lactation’, a curd-like substance is regurgitated from the crop to the chick. The dry-substance of pigeon ‘milk’ is 60% protein, 32-36% fat, 1-3% carbohydrate and some minerals, including calcium. It has been shown that pigeon ‘milk’ contains IgA antibodies, which provides evidence suggestive that it is more than a nutrients alone. The physiological mechanisms governing pigeon ‘milk’ production and delivery are unknown. It is well documented that the pigeon crop is responsive to the lactogenic hormone prolactin. However, the *pigeon crop tissue during ‘lactation’ is **structurally unrelated to the mammary glands** in mammalians, because it is not glandular and secretory processes do not seem to be involved* [(Gillespie *et al*, 2011)](http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1471-2164-12-452.pdf).

The similarity between this process and lactation in mammals is striking, but is a case of convergent evolution, where unrelated species independently evolve similar traits. 'Milk' production is also recorded in some **fishes**, where it is fed to their young in the form of a mucous secretion on the skin [(Buckley, 2010)](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/213/22/3787). Certain **amphibians** shed skin cells that are fed to the young. But the 'milk' of pigeons and doves is thought to be the most highly specialized of any non-mammalian 'milk' ([Australian Geographic, September 2011](http://www.australiangeographic.com.au/news/2011/09/mysteries-of-pigeon-milk-explained/)).

<sub>**References**

**-** [Buckley *et al*., *J Exp Biol*; **213**: 3787-95](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/213/22/3787)

**-** [Gillespie *et al.*, *BMC Genomics* (2011); **12**: 452](http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/pdf/1471-2164-12-452.pdf)</sub>

Comment: 'Milk'-producing fishes are something I really would not have expected. Cool.

(extra details at http://jeb.biologists.org/content/213/22/i.1.full.pdf+html?sid=82269227-a55f-4c15-982a-9b5f6f5fa6b0 )

Answer (score 28):

Producing milk, per se, is a strictly mammalian phenomenon. There are functionally similar processes in non-mammals (e.g., ['crop milk', produced by some birds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_milk)), but because these processes evolved independently from the evolution of mammalian milk, they are not considered to truly be milk.